# How to progress in gym after you hit weight loss plateau?

Tags: weightlifting, bodybuilding, gym

I am a big guy, I was 6 feet 2 and weighed 110 KG when I decided to get into better shape. I have had a fear of Gym and never went to one till now. I started doing weight lifting 4 days a week and cardio twice a week. I divided my Gym workout into Upper & Lower body workouts and also started to eat healthy high protein low carb diet.

The first 2 months I got very good results and lost 6 KG but then after that I have stalled and nothing I try seems to be working. I consume less than 1800 calories per day and keep my carb intake to less than 150 grams. Still for the past 2.5 months I haven't seen any change in my measurements or in the weight. The problem is that now when I train in gym some of my body parts don't feel the heat. When I try to do chest press with 15 KG dumbbells, I feel I am not  lifting enough weight, but I cannot go above 15 KG because my arms are not strong enough to support that weight. I need advise from someone who has been down the same road on what I am doing wrong and how to get out of the mental frustration state where I feel I am putting a lot of effort but it's not paying off.

I have been doing moderate cardio. I run for 30 minutes at a speed of 7.5 twice a week. HIIT is something I just cannot do in my current bad shape. Would really like to hear an advice from you guys.

Comment: Seeing comments like "I cannot do X" indicates you also have an attitude problem towards exercise.

Comment: I think I mentioned that my problem is my arms do not support more weight. I don't see how you can say it's attitude problem? You could have said just focus on making your arms more stronger first, that would have made more sense to me.

Comment: I think maybe he referred to "HIIT is something I just cannot do in my current bad shape". HIIT doesn't point to any fixed tempo you need to uphold. An intense interval is whatever tempo is intense for *you*, and that means that it's something you **can** do.

Comment: correct @Alec, I also find it impossible to believe that you could knock out a few sets of 8 reps of chest press with 15kg but cannot move up 1 dumbbell size and hit any reps at all.

Comment: @JJosaur I think I didn't explain in detail. What I mean by not going up is from 15 KG to 17.5 KG and with this weight I cannot complete 1 set of 8 proper reps.

Comment: All beginners should be doing linear programming. When I started I could barely do 1 rep at 50kg bench, yesterday I hit 3 reps at 77.5kg. I did that by upping the weight every time I could successfully complete all the reps in my sets for an exercise, read up on linear programming. http://people.brunel.ac.uk/~mastjjb/jeb/or/morelp.html

Comment: You can change up how you use the weights.  Example - let's say I can't do more than 60 lbs of barbell curls because of reasons like you said, but I can seemingly do 60 lbs without too much effort and am not progressing.  I could do 25 lb dumbells in each hand - high speed, 15 reps each side, then immediately grab 50 lb barbell and do "negative" curls, contract/up on a one count, lower the weight on a four count, until exhaustion sets in.  There are ways to vary your routine to overload the muscles.  Also, if shoulders, arms or stabilizers are a limiting factor, work on improving those.